# BLE advertising parameters

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

How can we advertise on a single advertising channel using bluez 4.101?

I have seen that there is `le_set_advertising_parameters` structure but that is not used, but in `bluez-5.7` code it is used where chan_map is set to 7 `chan_map=7`. What does this assignment mean? How is this mapping done?

Can that be done in bluez-4.101?

Answer (score 1):

Adv channels must be circulated 37,38,39 for BLE to work according to spec.
Once the connections has been established it is possible to exclude channels that have interference from wifi or other. The allowed channels at the channel mapping.
In certain chipsets you can reduce advertising channels for debugging purpose. Like if your ble sniffer only listened on one channel.
This is a bitmap with one bit per channel. 7 means all three adv channels. 1,2,4 is one channel each.

Comment: So according to you, we can select channel 37 for advertising using `chan_map = 1`, channel 38 for `chan_map = 2`, channel 39 for `chan_map = 4` and for using channel 38 & 39 `chan_map = 6` and so on. I'll give it a try. However I can't check it which channel is it using currently. I don't have the sniffer :( My chipset is WL1273L from TI

Comment: And in the sniffer we can listen on the particular channel, that may be done using the frequency check for the incoming packets and then determining the channel. Is it so? or configured through software